# How can I integrate Saucelabs with Playwright and Typescript framework?

Tags: typescript, playwright, saucelabs

I'm currently working on a playwright project and trying to implement a Saucelabs automation project for Playwright. I've worked with JAVA+SELENIUM for Saucelabs and also a little bit with JS and Saucelabs.

Wondering what could be an exact syntax build structure for config.ts file where I can define Saucelabs component like we do in JAVA.
THX!

Comment: Can you add some more detail about what you're trying to replicate from Java?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Saucelabs official docs for Playwright? https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/playwright/

Comment: In addition to what @demouser123 mentioned. Try going through this example https://github.com/saucelabs/saucectl-playwright-example/blob/main/.sauce/config.yml